# Jquery Ajax success callback from PHP turns up undefined

Tags: jquery

Im currently successfully submitting my Jquery AJAX post call to PHP.
However my callback from PHP is turning up as UNDEFINED.

**My PHP file:**

```
echo json_encode(array('returned_val' => 'returned from PHP'));
```

**Jquery:**

```
        //Save the data
        var url = "saveToDb.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

        var request = $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $("#formSubmit").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               success: function(data)
               {
                   alert(data.returned_val);
               },
               error:function() {
                    alert("failure");
                }   
             });
        return false;
```

In firebug the Net-Response header for my .php file call shows me:

```
{"returned_val":"returned from PHP"}
```

The JSON Net-JSON header tells me:

```
returned_val                    "returned from PHP"
```

Any suggestions on what im missing?

Comment: Does your PHP send a `Content-type; application/json` header?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
}).done(function(data){
    alert(data.returned_val);
```

}});

If you put dataType: 'json' it should already convert

Answer (score 0):

Better solution in below. Otherwise object child return "undefined"

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
}).done(function(data){

 alert(data.returned_val); // OUTPUT: "undefined"

 var object = $.parseJSON(data);

 alert(object.returned_val); // OUTPUT : "Your message"

});
```